# adding regular expression to form_validation in codeIgniter

Tags: regex, codeigniter, validation

I have number of forms with same structure. They all are same for user data. the id for these forms are addComment1, addComment2, addComment3, and etc.
I want to define form validation for each of them. but i don't know their numbers. I want to use regular expression for defining them in form_validation.php. They all have the same structure and form_validation function is same for all of them. How can I use regular expression to do it?

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field name', 'human name', 'regex_match[expression]');
```

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/195050/

Use search.